# Is there a way to migrate to CRA?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

When i had create my project i didn't know abuot create-react-app, but it's really good tool to reduce time that i've spending on webpack support.

Is there a way to migrate whole project to CRA?

Comment: You could create a new CRA project and just copy all your components and other config files across. I don't believe there is a way to migrate to it automatically because there are an infinite number of ways you can set up a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need a plan to migrate.
As i see, easiest way to migrate it's create new project with `create-react-app` and just paste your project src to the new place.

But there is figuring out few questions that you need to be ready to handle:

1. Is your test wrote on `jest`? If not, you need to migrate them.
2. Are in your project imports written in commajs style or es6 (`import` or `require`)? You need es6 style.
3. Are you using `npm` or `yarn`? CRA recommends `yarn`.